# ecryptfs - How does the passwd utility update the hash for non-admin password changes?

Tags: linux, encryption, passwords, password-encryption, ecryptfs

I have been playing around with `ecryptfs` to manually mount/unmount a private store via `ecryptfs-mount-private` and `ecryptfs-umount-private`. When I'm logged in as a user with `ecryptfs` configured (ie: username is **bob**), it asks for my login password for my Linux user account in order to mount the private store. If I change my password while I'm logged into the system via the `passwd` command line utility, `ecryptfs` requires my new password in order to mount the private store.

If I log in as the `root` user (ie: sysadmin) and change the password for the **bob** account via `sudo passwd bob`, and then log into Bob's account, `ecryptfs-mount-private` will fail when I use the new password I set while logged in as `root`.

My understanding is that `ecryptfs` uses a hash of the user password to generate another hash/key that's used to "wrap" the encrypted files in the private store. But if that's the case, why does it "just work" when I change the password when logged in as the actual user, but not when I reset the password as root?

My best guess so far is that maybe some setting is passed to the `passwd` utility which causes it to run a secondary script after completion. Does anyone know for sure how this works with `ecryptfs`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a user changes their own password, PAM ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_PAM)) gets called to re-wrap the eCryptfs passphrase with the new user passphrase, so you can decrypt your home the next time you log in.

Somehow, I don't know the exact line-by-line details, but I think I found a suspect line in `/etc/pam.d/common-password`:

```
password        optional        pam_ecryptfs.so
```

Unwrapping the eCryptfs passphrase should fail if root tries, since it doesn't have your user login passphrase. eCryptfs also explicitly tells you to backup the actual eCryptfs passphrase when it creates an encrypted home (maybe any encrypted private folder) since if something happens to the eCryptfs wrapped passphrase file, or you forget the login passphrase, the files will be effectively lost.

If root could change your eCryptfs passphrase whenever they wanted by changing your login passphrase, you would have no real security beyond root.